# The process rc could not be started

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to build my application using Qt and MSVC2015, this problem I am facing when I upgraded my qt to 5.12.0 earler it was building successfully  and I am getting the following error message :

> error: The process 'rc' could not be started: Process failed to start: The system cannot find the file specified.. The full command line invocation was: rc /nologo /d _MBCS /d WIN32 /d VIDEOLIB_LIBRARY /d USES_VIDEOLIB3 /d USES_MAGEWELLAIOSDK /d QT_CORE_LIB /d QT_GUI_LIB /d QT_OPENGL_LIB /d QT_WIDGETS_LIB /d NOMINMAX /d "QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x000000" /d "VERSION_ID=\"2.1-0\"" /d "VERSION_MAJOR=2" /d "VERSION_MINOR=1" /d "VERSION_REVISION=0" /d LEIBINGER_PLUGIN_EXPORTS /d _WIN32_DCOM /d NO_DSHOW_STRSAFE /d "WDM_VIDEO_SUPPORT=1" /d USES_QT /d USES_OPENGL_EMBEDDED /d USES_OPENGL_DESKTOP /d STRYKER_LIBRARIES_DYNAMIC /d _DEBUG /d __mswin__ /d WIN32 /d "USE_RVALUE_REFS=1" /d _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /d _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /d USES_CLASSLIB /d USES_LOG4CPP /i

Comment: I've scrolled through your `rc` command line 2 times and found lots of defines (`/d`) and other settings. What I missed was a `.rc` file. Are you sure that you didn't forget something?

Comment: "*The system cannot find the file specified*" - seems pretty self explanatory to me.

Comment: On our side, we are using VS to compile our Qt appl. with a "hand-written" `.rc` file. In the Qt doc. this is mentioned as one option but it seems there are more: [Setting the Application Icon on Windows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html#setting-the-application-icon-on-windows).

Comment: @RemyLebeau If the issue is really that the `.rc` file is simply missing then I would've found _"No input file specified!"_ self explanatory... ;-)

Comment: I'm still not certain how I should understand the error message. Does it mean the `.rc` file is missing (in project) or does it mean the resource compiler (`rc.exe`) cannot be foun?. Concerning the latter, I found: [Qt Forum: LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'](https://forum.qt.io/topic/90839/lnk1158-cannot-run-rc-exe).